# Insert a new record if not exist and update if exist Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Here's my configController code :

```
public function save(Request $request, $obj = null) {

    if (!$obj) {
        $obj = new Config;
    }
    else{
        $obj = Config::firstOrNew(array('id' => Input::get('id')));
        $obj->save();
    }
    return $this->saveHandler($request, $obj);
}
}
```

it didn't work, any idea ?

Comment: What do you pass as $obj to this method? This value doesn't seem to be used for anything except the IF as it's later overwritten. I'm not sure what your intention here is.